# Swift class object sends its value when calling a function

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a function inside a class that need to get the value of the object and then return a different value. I want to do something like what apple do with CLLocation distance. Where you can call

```
    point1.distance(point2)
```

where the value of both point1 and point2 are sent.

I know I could create a function and send the parameter in the function like this:

```
getDistance(point1: Location, point2: Location)
```

Is there is any way to use the more elegant style the function and how its being called, like the way Apple uses their fucntions.

Comment: If both methods you wrote existed and worked, what it may look like internally would be in pseudo code: `point1.distance(point2){getDistance(point1:self, point2:point2)}`. Does this give you an hint?

Comment: So you want to create a [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID234)?

Comment: Thank you very much, I created a function inside the class "Method" and I used self inside the method, and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
class Location {

private var _position: Double!

var position: Double {
    return _position
}

init(position: Double) {

    self._position = position
}

func distance (reference: Location) -> Double {
    let point1 = self.position //or whatever leads to your value
    let point2 = reference.position
    //do what ever you have to do with both points e.g.
    let result = point1 - point2
    return result
}
```

}

```
let point1 = Location(position: 50.0)

let point2 = Location(position: 32.0)
```

now you can do your desired thing:

```
point1.distance(reference: point2)

// returns 18
```